# Overloading less than operator in c++ for use in std::sort

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have a struct defined like this:

```
struct IFSFunc {
    int a;

    bool operator<(const IFSFunc& other) {
        return a < other.a;
    }
};
```

Since `IFSfunc` is a `struct`, access modifier for the `operator<` should be `public`.

I also have this code:

```
#include <algorithm>
std::vector<std::pair<double, IFSFunc>> ifsFuncs;

// fill the vector with various data

std::sort(ifsFuncs.begin(), ifsFuncs.end());
```

I need to sort ifsFuncs based on the first `double` in the pair. I don't care about `IFSFunc` structure, if the `double` is the same.

However, for std::sort to work, which is defined like this:

```
template <class _Ty1, class _Ty2>
_NODISCARD constexpr bool operator<(const pair<_Ty1, _Ty2>& _Left, const pair<_Ty1, _Ty2>& _Right) {
    return _Left.first < _Right.first || (!(_Right.first < _Left.first) && _Left.second < _Right.second);
}
```

I have to override the less than operator for the `second` in this case `IFSfunc`, which I did. However, trying to compile this code gives me the following error:

```
Error C2678 binary '<': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const _Ty2' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Why?

Comment: There is no need for a separate function:  `std::sort(ifsFuncs.begin(), ifsFuncs.end(), [] (IFSFunc& f1, IFSFunc& f2) { return f1.a < f2.a; });`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define that operator as a const member function.

Also, don't just return true for a comparison. That can result in infinite looping.

Comment: The true here was just to simplify the code as much as possible. I've changed it to compare an arbitrary value.

Answer (score 0):

I just figure it out. The overloaded function signature was wrong, this is what I need:

```
struct IFSFunc {
    int a;

    bool operator<(const IFSFunc& other) const {
        return a < other.a;
    }
};
```

Notice that the `operator<` is now a const function.

Comment: Why not use a lambda function inside the `sort` call?  You then don't need a separate function.